# Speeding up rowwise comparison

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, vectorization

I have a `data.frame` like the following:

```
id year  x y         v1
 1 2006 12 1  0.8510703
 1 2007 12 1  0.5954527
 1 2008 12 2 -1.9312854
 1 2009 12 1  0.1558393
 1 2010  8 1  0.9051487
 2 2001 12 2 -0.5480566
 2 2002 12 2 -0.7607420
 2 2003  3 2 -0.8094283
 2 2004  3 2 -0.1732794
```

I would like to sum up (grouped by `id`) `v1` of consecutive years (so 2010 and 2009, 2009 and 2008 and so on) only if `x` and `y` match. Expected output:

```
id year        res
 1 2010         NA
 1 2009         NA
 1 2008         NA
 1 2007  1.4465230
 2 2004 -0.9827077
 2 2003         NA
 2 2002 -1.3087987
```

The oldest `year` per `id` is removed, as there is no preceding year.

I have a slow `lapply` solution in place but would like to speed things up, as my data is rather large.

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4)),year = c(2006:2010,2001:2004),
                x = c(12,12,12,12,8,12,12,3,3), y = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                v1 = rnorm(9))
```

Current Solution:

```
require(dplyr)

myfun <- function(dat) { do.call(rbind,lapply(rev(unique(dat$year)[-1]),
            function(z) inner_join(dat[dat$year==z,2:5],
            dat[dat$year==z-1,2:5],
            by=c("x","y")) %>%
            summarise(year = z, res = ifelse(nrow(.) < 1,NA,sum(v1.x,v1.y))))) 
        }

dat %>% group_by(id) %>% do(myfun(.))
```

Comment: @Imo true, but the `sum` of `v1` is not really of importance. But I will update my question.

Comment: Your `dat` doesn't match the example at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution, I think.

```
datNew <- setDT(dat)[, .(year=year, res=(v1+shift(v1)) * NA^(x != shift(x) | y != shift(y))),
                     by=id][-1, .SD, by=id][]
   id year        res
1:  1 2007 -0.4428105
2:  1 2008         NA
3:  1 2009         NA
4:  1 2010         NA
5:  2 2001         NA
6:  2 2002 -0.3330393
7:  2 2003         NA
8:  2 2004  1.3141061
```

Here, the j statement contains a list with two elements, the year and a function. This function sums values with the lagged value, using `shift`, but is multiplied by NA or 1 depending on whether the x and y match with their lagged values. This calculation is performed by id. The output is fed to a second chain, which drops the first observation of each id which is all NA.

You can adjust the order efficiently using `setorder` if desired.

```
setorder(datNew, id, -year)

datNew
   id year        res
1:  1 2010         NA
2:  1 2009         NA
3:  1 2008         NA
4:  1 2007 -0.4428105
5:  2 2004  1.3141061
6:  2 2003         NA
7:  2 2002 -0.3330393
8:  2 2001         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are sorted years as in the example:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(res = v1 + lag(v1),                                     #simple lag for difference                            
         res = ifelse(x == lag(x) & y == lag(y), v1, NA)) %>%    #NA if x and y don't match
  slice(-1)                                                      #drop the first year
```

You can use `%>% select(id, year, res)`, and `%>% arrange(id, desc(year))` at the end if you want.